# Display data based on selected start and end date in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using full calendar. And I displayed some contents in a calendar.

1) By default it has showing data in all date field.

2) I have start date and end date calendar on top. I want to display data based on the selected start and end date. For example, if I select startdate `01/08/2016` and enddate `14/08/2016`.

I want to display data based on the start and end dates only.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3jyxs6Lc/1/)

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
 header: {
  left: 'prev,next today',
  center: 'title',
  right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
 },
 defaultDate: '2014-06-12',
 editable: true,
});
$("td.fc-day.fc-widget-content").each(function( index ) {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
    $(this).append("<span style='font-size: 30px;font-weight: 600;color: green;'>"+random+"%</span>");
});
```

```css
body {
 margin-top: 40px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 13px;
 font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
}

#calendar {
 width: 900px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
Start Date :<input type="text" id="endDate" name="end_datum" class="input_text" value=""> 
End date :<input type="text" id="endDate" name="end_datum" class="input_text" value=""></br></br></br></br>

<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: How are you getting your calendar events? If with a database, you can just use ajax to send the two dates and build a query to get and return events between the two dates.

Comment: I am not using events. I directly displayed in td content like, $("td.fc-day.fc-widget-content").each(function( index ) {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in my example I use start and end as a static variable you will need to grab the input from start and end to use it dynamically. So assign your start and end dates, then we will assign `date` as the current objects `date` attribute value. Then we will create a moment with that date called `day` and use an if statement to make sure that `day` is greater than `start` and less than `end` and if it passes then you have your handling code. Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3jyxs6Lc/3/).

```
$("td.fc-day.fc-widget-content").each(function( index ) {
    var start = moment('2014-06-04'); //start date from start date input
    var end = moment('2014-06-18'); //end date from end date input
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
    var date = $(this).data('date'); //get current date in loop
    var day = moment(date); //create a moment

    //if day is greater than start date and less than end date, display.
    if(day > start && day < end) {
        $(this).append("<span style='font-size: 30px;font-weight: 600;color: green;'>"+random+"%</span>");
    }
});
```

Comment: I need one more help. Here I am not using fullCalendar Events function. Is this possible to do the same thing using fullCalendar events insteat of using $("td.fc-day.fc-widget-content").each(function(){

Comment: Yes it is possible. If your events are from a database you could just pass in your dates with ajax to build your query to return only those events, or you can use [clientEvents](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/clientEvents/) to access all your visible events and work with them from there. If they are from a json feed you could work with the dates in javascript and momentjs. I suggest you read through all the [fullcalendar docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/) it will help you learn all of the things you can work with.